# Ember.js Select selected option

Tags: ember.js

I'm attempting to recreate forms from a Rails app into an Ember.js app. I need to do a select for an association, with a selected option. I have tried literally everything I can think of and find reference to in guides and blog posts, but have not managed to get anything working. No idea how to sort the options eg by name ascending, but that may be another question entirely.

This is the basic idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

#### Route:

```
BillingEmber.QuotesEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  setupController: (controller, model)->
    controller.set('model', model)
    controller.set('clients', @store.find('client'))
    controller.set('selectedClient', model.get('client.id'))
)
```

#### Template:

```
{{view Ember.Select 
  content=clients
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  selection=selectedClient}}
```

Comment: Matthew, that answers my question perfectly, thank you so much, so what I have working now is dropping the "selectedClient" from route, and adding selection=client to the select. Works! If you want to make your comment answer I will accept it.

Comment: Happy to help, Gordon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is pretty much how you want to set up a select... `selection` uses a model to match against your `content` collection, so use

```
model.get('client')
```

instead of

```
model.get('client.id')
```